# Python loop through list to get api call in asyncio and save results

Tags: python, request, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I don't fully understand how asyncio and aiohttp work yet.

I am trying to make a bunch of asynchronous api requests from a list of urls and save them as a variable so I can processes them later.

so far I am generating the list which is no problem and setting up the request framework.

```
urls = []
for i in range(0,20):
    urls.append('https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol={}&interval= 
    {}&limit={}'.format(pairs_list_pairs[i],time_period,
            pull_limit))

import asyncio
import aiohttp


async def request(url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get(url) as resp:
            return await resp.text()


async def main():
    results = await asyncio.gather(
             request(urls[0]),
             request(urls[1]),
    )
    print(len(results))
    print(results)



loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
try:
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
    loop.run_until_complete(loop.shutdown_asyncgens())
finally:
    loop.close()
```

If I manually type out my requests one by one using indexing (like below), I can make the request. But the problem is that my list has upwards of 100 apis requests that I don't want to type by hand. How can I iterate through my list? Also how can I save my results into a variable? When the script ends it does not save "results" anywhere.

```
async def main():
    results = await asyncio.gather(
             request(urls[0]),
             request(urls[1]),
    )
    print(len(results))
    print(results)
```

Below are some sample urls to replicate the code:

```
[
 'https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=ETHBTC&interval=15m&limit=1',
 'https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=LTCBTC&interval=15m&limit=1',
 'https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=BNBBTC&interval=15m&limit=1',
 'https://api.binance.com/api/v1/klines?symbol=NEOBTC&interval=15m&limit=1',
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pass a variable number of arguments to `gather`, use the `*` function argument syntax:

```
results = await asyncio.gather(*[request(u) for u in urls])
```

Note that `f(*args)` is a standard Python feature to invoke `f` with positional arguments calculated at run-time.

`results` will be available once all requests are done, and they will be in a list in the same order as the URLs. Then you can return them from `main`, which will cause them to be returned by `run_until_complete`.

Also, you will have much better performance if you create the session only once, and reuse it for all requests, e.g. by passing it as a second argument to the `request` function.

Answer (score 1):

Using `gather` and a helper function (`request`) are only making a quite simple task more complicated and difficult to work with. You can simply use the same `ClientSession` throughout all your individual requests with a loop whilst saving each response into a resultant list.

```
async def main():
    results = []
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for url in urls:
            async with session.get(url) as resp:
                results.append(await resp.text())
    print(len(results))
    print(results)
```

---

For the other part of your question, when you said:

> When the script ends it does not save "results" anywhere.

if you meant that you want to access `results` outside of the `main` coroutine, you simply can add a `return` statement.

At the end of `main`, add:

```
return results
```

and change

```
loop.run_until_complete(main())
# into:
results = loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

Comment: Replacing `gather` with a `for` loop as shown above will cause the requests to be retrieved one after the other rather than in parallel.